# R - Unbind Dataframe

Tags: r, for-loop, lapply

I am trying to split a dataframe (df) into its constituent vectors

Example dataframe

```
v1 <- c(213, 225, 435)
v2 <- c(333, 888, 999)
v2 <- c(788, 666, 545)

df <- data.frame(v1, v2, v3)
```

Current syntax:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste('v', i, sep = '')) <- df$v[c(i)]
}
```

Desired output is just:

v1, v2, v3

Is there a way to do this using lapply?  Is there a way to do this using a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the `assign`, we specify the `value` argument and the `x` (which is object name as a string).  Also `v[c(i)]` is incorrect as `i` is a numeric index and it is trying to subset `v` which doesn't exist.  Inside it would be the same `paste` to create the column name along with `[[` for dynamic subsetting

```
for (i in 1:3) {
  assign(paste('v', i, sep = ''), value = df[[paste0("v", i)]])
 }
```

Or instead of calling `paste` twice, can do

```
for(i in 1:3) {
    nm1 <- paste0("v", i)
    assign(nm1, value = df[[nm1]])
}
```

---

Or another option is

```
rm(list = paste0('v', 1:3)) # // remove the objects created in the env
list2env(df, .GlobalEnv)
v1
#[1] 213 225 435
v2
#[1] 788 666 545
v3
#[1] 788 666 545
```

---

Or can use `attach` as well.  It is better not to create multiple objects in the global environment.  Instead, it can be in a `list` or `data.frame` (if the objects are of equal length)

Answer (score 0):

Use `split.default` to split every column into different dataframe.

```
res <- split.default(df, names(df))
res

#$v1
#   v1
#1 213
#2 225
#3 435

#$v2
#   v2
#1 333
#2 888
#3 999

#$v3
#   v3
#1 788
#2 666
#3 545
```

Use `list2env` if you need them as separate objects.

```
list2env(res, .GlobalEnv)
```